# How can I know an Activity launched from dynamic shortcuts when I use singleTask?

Tags: android

`ActivityMain` is singleTask.

I can use Code A to create a dynamic shortcuts icon in screen, it will show `ActivityMain` when I click the shortcuts icon.

You know I can also show ActivityMain by clicking the app icon.

How can I know a Activity lanuched from dynamic shortcuts when I use singleTask ?

BTW, Code B doesn't work.

**Code A**

```
 @TargetApi(25)
    private fun createShorcut() {
        val sM = getSystemService(ShortcutManager::class.java)
        val intent1 = Intent(this, ActivityMain::class.java)

        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent1.setAction("My")

        val shortcut1 = ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, "shortcut1")
            .setIntent(intent1)
            .setShortLabel("Shortcut 1")
            .setLongLabel("Shortcut 2")
            .setShortLabel("This is the shortcut 1")
            .setDisabledMessage("Login to open this")
            .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.notify_icon))
            .build()
        sM.dynamicShortcuts = Arrays.asList(shortcut1)
    }


    @TargetApi(25)
    private fun removeShorcuts() {
        val shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager::class.java)
        shortcutManager.disableShortcuts(Arrays.asList("shortcut1"))
        shortcutManager.removeAllDynamicShortcuts()
    }


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 25) {
            createShorcut()
    }else{
            removeShorcuts()
    }

   <activity android:name=".ui.ActivityMain"
           android:launchMode="singleTask">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

**Code B**

```
  override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        if (mActivity.intent.action.equals("My")) {
            toast("ActivityMain from dynamic shortcuts")
        }
   }
```

**Added Content:**

To prateek: Thanks!

Do you mean I have to check it both onCreate and onNewIntent event when I use SingleTask?

In SingleTask:

A: When I run the APP (Click either App Icon or Shortcut Icon) for the first time, only onCreate event is fired.

B: If the app is already running, when I fire the App again (Click either App Icon or Shortcut Icon) , only onNewIntent event is fired.

So I have to check it both onCreate and onNewIntent event just like Code C, right?

**Code C**

```
  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnClose).setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }

        createShorcut()

        var which= this.intent.getBooleanExtra("yourkey", false)

        displayResult(which)
    }


    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)

        var which= intent?.getBooleanExtra("yourkey", false)

         displayResult(which?:false)
    }

    private fun displayResult(which:Boolean){
        if (which) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "From ShortCut Icon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "From App Icon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    private fun createShorcut() {
        val sM = getSystemService(ShortcutManager::class.java)
        val intent1 = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)

        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent1.setAction("My")
        intent1.putExtra("yourkey", true)

        val shortcut1 = ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, "ShortCut Item")
                .setIntent(intent1)
                .setShortLabel("Shortcut Item")
                .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground))
                .build()
        sM.dynamicShortcuts = Arrays.asList(shortcut1)
    }
}


      <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my use case, I am adding a flag when creating intent to be launched via shortcut and always able to retrieve it at the other end.
Try something like `.putExtra("fromShortcut", true)`. It should work.
Regarding retrieving action I haven't tried, sorry.

[Update]

This is how I am creating my intent object:

```
val shortcutIntent = Intent(context, YourActivity::class.java)
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
                .putExtra("yourkey", true)
                .addFlags(
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                )
```

and this is how you retrieve it at the receiving end:

```
mNewIntentReceived.getBooleanExtra("yourkey", false)
```

Also, I can observe you are not adding 'new task' flag in your intent, add that as well.

Comment: If you launch ActivityMain first, then put it to background, and show it again by clicking shortcuts icon, the ActivityMain will be shown again from background without recreate, so `putExtra("fromShortcut", true)` will not be launched!

Comment: If there's already an activity in the task, then as per your mentioned launch mode, it wont call onCreate() rather onNewIntent() would be called. You can handle things there then.

Comment: Thanks! when `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, `onNewIntent() ` isn't always launched!

Comment: As already mentioned, it depends on your use case. When activity is not present in any task, it is created and onNewIntent() wont be called but if it is there in some task, then its onCreate() isnt called rather onNewIntent().
This was in reference to your mentioned launch mode. This behaviour varies with different launch modes.

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean that I can't know exactly which launch activity   between clicking App Icon and clicking shortcut icon in SingleTask model?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your query, it lacks clarity. Still, in general, you always know which activity would be launched when because you have only coded in your Intents. Also, again re-iterating, it depends on how user is navigating/launching the app and accordingly either it would be created by calling onCreate() or if already present in a task, its onNewIntent() would be called. I strongly recommend you to go through launch mode documentation on Android's developer site to get a better understanding. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: Seen your code, correct! You have to retrieve your value in both cases/methods since there can be these 2 entry points to your activity. Good job!